# COUNTRI get an error when I run my query even though the syntax is correct

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table named `CUSTOMERS` with a column `COUNTRY`. I want to retrieve the city that has the most customers, in other words the most frequent `COUNTRY` in table `CUSTOMERS`.

I get an error message as following:

> ORA-00904: "COUNTRY": invalid identifier

My code:

```
SELECT 
    COUNTRY,
    COUNT(COUNTRY) AS `value_occurrence` 
FROM 
    CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY 
    COUNTRY
ORDER BY 
    `value_occurrence` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: where    rownum<=1;

Comment: show sample data!!!

Comment: You say `CITY` in your description, but in your code you use `COUNTRY`. Please clarify.

Comment: Do you have column country? But why country when you need city?

Comment: Oracle DB is not the same as MySQL DB though they both are published by Oracle

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I tried as you suggested.  SELECT COUNTRY,
COUNT(COUNTRY) AS 'value_occurrence'
FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY COUNTRY
ORDER BY 'value_occurrence' DESC
WHERE rownum<1;  but got an error.  ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @MladenS I'm sorry for the confusion.  There's no city column I wrote city by mistake.  I edited the question.

Comment: @WafaAlOmar - your question has the column alias in backticks; an earlier comment has the alias in single quotes. Neither is right, and the latter will give you the ORA-00923 error. It should be `... AS value_occurrence` with no quotes. (You *can* double-quote, but it's not usually needed or desirable). But your comment is also wrong in other ways... Also, which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: On a side note: `COUNT(country)` is a bad idea. It counts non-null occurrences of the column `country`. As you group by `country`, all countries in a group will be the same, i.e. all either null or not null. That means for all countries you just get the row count and for country null you get zero instead of the row count. Use `COUNT(*)` when you want to count rows.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is MySQL, which is not portable. MySQL is another DBMS than Oracle.

Here is your query in standard SQL. It works in Oracle as of version 12c.

```
select country, count(*) as value_occurrence
from customers
order by value_occurrence desc
fetch first row only;
```

In earlier Oracle versions you can use:

```
select country, value_occurrence
from
(
  select 
    country,
    count(*) as value_occurrence,
    row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
  from customers
)
where rn = 1;
```

If you want to allow for ties, then you'd change `only` to `with ties` in the first query and `row_number` to `rank` or `dense_rank` in the second.